# Reading Data by Year (col) and Month(row)

Tags: mysql, sql

I really need your help on a mysql query where I am not getting any clue.

Say I have a table with two columns:

```
entryDate - datetime
Recruits - int
```

I am trying to building a mysql query to get the output like the image. Please share the query.

[image: Sample Output Data]

Comment: `Please share the query` ... I was just going to ask you that.  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: _"I am not getting any clue"_ What have you tried? Anything?

Comment: no idea so far on how to put the year on column. May be Pivot will work, not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation and arithmetic:

```
select monthname(entryDate) as mon,
       sum(case when year(entryDate) = 2016 then recruits else 0 end) as recruits_2016,
       sum(case when year(entryDate) = 2017 then recruits else 0 end) as recruits_2017,
       (sum(case when year(entryDate) = 2017 then recruits end) /
        sum(case when year(entryDate) = 2017 then recruits end) 
       ) - 1 as change
from t
where entryDate between '2016-01-01' and entryDate < '2018-01-01'
group by monthname(entryDate)
order by min(entryDate);
```

Comment: Thanks, why this -1 in change?

Comment: @user1795928 . . . To get the values that you specify in the column.